# Integral of square of the Brownian Motion with respect to time

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Is there anything known about the distribution of:
$$ \int_0^1 B_t^2 \; dt \; ?$$
I know that without squaring, the distribution of the above variable is normal with mean $0$ and variance $\frac{1}{3}$ (https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/29504/integral-of-brownian-motion-w-r-t-time). But if underlying process is nonnegative, the distribution obviously cannot be normal and from simulation I can only conclude that it has mean $\frac{1}{2}$ (which is actually easy to prove) and variance $\frac{1}{3}$. But the exact distribution is unknown to me. Is there any source of information about such integral?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the right mean and variance for

$$ \int_0^1 B_t^2 \; dt \; ?$$

But, its distribution is not of any known functions. In fact, it is rather complex. You may find some research results in the link below.

https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1020107767

Answer (score 5):

You can actually compute the integral with the formula $d(tY_t) = Y_t \, dt + t \, dY_t$. Fixing $Y_t = B_t^2$, you have by Itô formula that $dY_t = 2B_t dB_t + dt$ and therefore
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 B_t^2 d t &= \int_0^1 d(tB_t^2) - \int_0^1 td(B_t^2)\\
&= B_1^2 - \int_0^12tB_tdB_t - \int_0^1tdt\\\
&= B_1^2 - \frac12 - \int_0^12tB_tdB_t.
\end{align}
With this expression (and Itô isometry) you can easily compute the second moment, and have a good idea of the distribution of your object.

For the variance, let
$$
Z = \int_0^1 B_t^2 d t.
$$
Then, since $E(B_1^4) = 3$, applying the Itô isometry and the properties of the Itô integral (zero mean) we get
\begin{align}
 E (Z^2) &= E\left(\left(B_1^2 - \frac12 - \int_0^12tB_tdB_t\right)^2\right) \\
&= E(B_1^4) + \frac14 + E\left(\left(\int_0^12tB_tdB_t\right)^2\right) - E (B_1^2)\\\
&\quad -2E\left(B_1^2\int_0^12tB_tdB_t\right) + E\left(\int_0^12tB_tdB_t\right) \\
&= 3 + \frac14 + \int_0^14t^2E(B_t^2)dt  -1 - \frac83+ 0\\
&=2+\frac14+\int_0^14t^3 dt-\frac83\\
&= 3+\frac14-\frac83 = \frac13 + \frac14,
\end{align}
where we used the fact that
$$
E\left(B_1^2\int_0^12tB_tdB_t\right) = \frac43
$$
Therefore, since $E(Z) = 1/2$ (easy to compute)
$$
\mathrm{Var}(Z) = E(Z^2) - E(Z)^2 = \frac13.
$$

Comment: I think I made a mistake somewhere, it is indeed 1/3. I'll double check. My result is for sure wrong since by Cauchy-Schwarz the variance has to be smaller than 1.

Comment: To add bit more details, $E\left(B_1^2\int_0^12tB_tdB_t\right) = E\left(\int_0^1 d(B_t^2)\int_0^12tB_tdB_t\right) \stackrel{Isometry}{=} E\left(\int_0^1 2tB_td\langle{B,B^2}\rangle_t \right) = E\left(\int_0^1 4tB_t^2dt\right)=4/3$

Comment: Yes. By the way, there is the same post in https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/30730/variance-of-time-integral-of-squared-brownian-motion

Comment: Yes, indeed. Another way to compute the moments, one can do: $E[\int_0^1 B_s^2ds]=\int_0^1E[B_s^2]ds=1/2$. For the second moment, $E[(\int_0^1 B_s^2ds)^2]=E[\int_0^1\int_0^1 B_s^2B_t^2dsdt]$ and we use the symmetry and the martingale property of $B_t^2$. Any idea about the distribution ?

Answer (score 3):

This question has been asked before in this forum.  My answer in [Determining distribution of $X_t = \int_0^t W_s^2 \mathrm{d} s$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99021/determining-distribution-of-x-t-int-0t-w-s2-mathrmd-s/99080#99080) gives a couple of references to the original solution of Cameron & Martin, and a different approach of M. Kac.