# Is this process a Brownian motion?

Tags: brownian-motion, quadratic-variation

I have some problem with deciding whether the process $Y_t$ is a Brownian motion. Here is the structure:

$X_t = \int_0^tW_s^2ds$ where $\{W_t\}_{t≥0}$ is a Brownian motion, and $Y_t=\frac{X_t-\frac{1}{2}t^2}{\frac{1}{2}t^{3/2}}$.

So here are what I did:

I calculated the mean and variance for $X$ and $Y$: $\mathbb{E}X_t=\frac{1}{2}t^2$, $\text{Var}X_t= \frac{1}{3}t^4$, $\mathbb{E}Y_t=0$, $\text{Var}Y_t= \frac{4}{3}t$.

I didn’t find the wrong places in my calculations. I found the variance of $Y_t$ is not $t$, so I wanted to say that $Y_t$ is not a Brownian motion. But I feel this argument is not that convincing. I am wondering there might be something wrong but I didn’t notice. Could you give me a convincing proof on whether $Y_t $ is a Brownian motion or not?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you explain how you calculated $\mbox{Var}(X_t)$? In particular, how did you find $E[X_t^2]$?

Comment: Here is a similar question:[link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3387795/integral-of-square-of-the-brownian-motion-with-respect-to-time)

Comment: Oh, I see, we write it as a double integral, very smart. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know what the $\mathbb{E}(X_tX_s)$ is? Is this equal to zero? Thank you.

Comment: As explained in the link given, $E[\int_0^t W_u^2du \int_0^s W_v^2dv] = \int_0^t \int_0^s E[W_u^2W_v^2]dudv$ by Tonelli's theorem (non-negative integrand). The inner integral can be calculated by using independence and stationarity of increments, take $u>v$ and $v>u$ separately for this and split. Alternately, you can use Ito's formula to write those integrals as Ito integrals, and use the Ito isometry to simplify vastly.

Comment: Thank you. So can I say $Y_t$ is not a Brownian motion because its variance isn’t $t$?

Comment: Can I write an answer confirming that? So you can accept it and close it?

Comment: Yes please. A detailed answer would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I will do that, just in short time

Comment: I have deleted the previous answer because I am trying to figure out the error in my argument which tried to avoid using the Ito isometry. I will get back on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note : From Danny's observation, we already know that $Y_t$ cannot be a Brownian motion as it is pathwise differentiable. However, I wish to derive the mean and variance of $Y_t$ for the sake of computation, as OP has demanded this of me.

---

To calculate the mean and variance of $Y_t$ we need to find the respective quantities for $X_t$.

Now, $E[X_t] = E\left[\int_0^t W_s^2 ds\right]$. We can exchange the integral and expectation since the integrand is non-negative hence Tonelli's theorem applies. Thus, $E[X_t] =  \int_0^t E[W_s^2]ds  = \int_0^t sds = \frac{t^2}{2}$.

Now, $E[X_t^2] = E\left[\left(\int_0^t W_s^2ds\right)^2\right] = E[\int_0^t W_s^2ds \int_{0}^t W_u^2du] = E\left[\int_0^t\int_0^t W_s^2W_u^2\ du\ ds\right]$. Once again, we have Tonelli applying here, and we get :
$$
E[X_t^2] = \int_0^t \int_0^t E[W_s^2W_u^2] duds
$$

Now, we will calculate the inner expectation for the case that $s > u$, and then for $u>s$ we can just switch the roles of $u$ and $s$. The advantage of doing that is that we may then write:
$$
W_s^2W_u^2 = ((W_s - W_u)+W_u)^2W_u^2 = (W_s-W_u)^2W_u^2 + 2(W_s-W_u)W_u^3 + W_u^4
$$

and therefore by independence and stationarity of increments :
$$
E[W_s^2W_u^2] = E[(W_s - W_u)^2]E[W_u^2] + 2E[(W_s - W_u)]E[W_u^3] + E[W_u^4] \\ = (s-u)u + 3u^2 = 2u^2 + us
$$

For $u>s$ we have $2s^2+su$. So we have :
$$
E[X_t^2] = \int_0^t \left(\int_0^s (2u^2+us)du + \int_s^t (2s^2+us)du\right) ds \\
= \int_0^t \left[\frac{7s^3}{6} + \frac {s}{2}(-5s^2+4st+t^2)\right]ds\\ =\left[\frac 16\left(-2s^4+4s^3t+\frac{3s^2t^2}{2}\right)\right]^t_0
\\ = \frac{7t^4}{12}
$$

and therefore $\mbox{Var}[X_t] = E[X_t^2] - E[X_t]^2 = \frac{7t^4}{12} - \frac{t^4}{4} = \frac{1}{3}t^4$, which matches the correct answer.

---

Now, $E[Y_t] = 2t^{-\frac 32} (E[X_t] -\frac 12 t^2) = 0$.

Then $\mbox{Var}[Y_t] = 4t^{-3}\mbox{Var}(X_t) = \frac {4t}3$, which doesn't match with the variance of a Brownian motion $B_t$ at time $t$.

Comment: It seems that a simple scaling of $Y_t$ cannot make it a Brownian motion. Reason: Recall that if a process $W$ is a Brownian motion, there exists a set $\Omega_0$ with $P(\Omega_0)=1$ such that for each $\omega\in\Omega_0$, the path $t\mapsto W(t,\omega)$ is nowhere differentiable. However, this is not the case for $t\mapsto Y(t,\omega)$.

Comment: Note that all the sample paths $t\mapsto Y(t,\omega)$ are differentiable. Therefore, $Y$ cannot be a Brownian motion.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Yes, you are correct! So $Y_t$ could never have been a Brownian motion in the first place. I should edit that in

Comment: Hi, I think Var(X) should be $\frac{1}{3}t^4$. Please see [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/30730/variance-of-time-integral-of-squared-brownian-motion). Perhaps you want to fix your answer a little bit?

Comment: @Cyan I see the error, but I think I will delete the answer because my effort has not been dedicated enough for this question. I will edit it and repost it again.

Comment: @Cyan The advantage of good sleep : I did not compute one of the integrals properly earlier, it is now correct. Thank you for informing me of the mistake. The most *elementary* way of finding the variance, without the use of Ito's formula unlike other posts.

Answer (score 2):

$Y$ is not a Brownian motion because the sample path $t\mapsto Y(t,\omega)$ is differentiable for each $\omega\in\Omega$.